# Quarkus 3.2.4 - Native exec error: No Converter registered for class io.quarkus.runtime.logging.InheritableLevel

Tags: quarkus

I've got a simple quarkus command application, using the picocli plugin. It runs fine when packaged using fast-jar and uber-jar.  However when running the native application, it fails with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:70)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:44)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SRCFG00013: No Converter registered for class io.quarkus.runtime.logging.InheritableLevel
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig.requireConverter(SmallRyeConfig.java:484)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig.getConverter(SmallRyeConfig.java:473)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.generated.Config.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

I'm using a YAML configuration file with specified profiles to help configure a few of the AWS services.

An exerpt from my `application.yml`

```yaml
quarkus:
  native:
    enable-https-url-handler: true
    additional-build-args: --initialize-at-run-time=io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl,--initialize-at-run-time=io.quarkus.runtime.generated.Config
  profile: awslocal
  secretsmanager:
    aws:
      region: ${aws.region}

aws:
  user-name: ${USER:none}

'%awslocal':
  aws:
    region: local

'%awsdev':
  aws:
    region: us-east-2
```

I feel like there's something that's not being registered for reflection somewhere, but I'm not exactly sure where the problem lies.  Has anyone seen this before? or have a suggestion for what could be missing from my native executable?

My `build.gradle` looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.quarkus'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:url-connection-client'
    implementation 'io.quarkiverse.amazonservices:quarkus-amazon-secretsmanager'
    implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:quarkus-amazon-services-bom:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-graphql-client'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-jackson'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-picocli'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-config-yaml'
    implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-arc'

    implementation 'org.orekit:orekit:11.3.3'

    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
}

group 'com.mycompany'
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

test {
    systemProperty "java.util.logging.manager", "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
}
compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.compilerArgs << '-parameters'
}

compileTestJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

and the associated `gradle.properties` is as follows:

```
quarkusPluginVersion=3.2.4.Final
quarkusPlatformArtifactId=quarkus-bom
quarkusPluginId=io.quarkus
quarkusPlatformGroupId=io.quarkus.platform
quarkusPlatformVersion=3.2.4.Final
```

I originally removed the `quarkus.native.additional-build-args` from the application-yml, but that just causes the build to fail. I hadn't see this issue until bringing in the aws secretmananger client, but the error in the core configuration is confusing. Is there some configuration I'm missing?

I'm thinking it's got something to do with the variable interpolation i'm using, but i can't figure which other classes i need to add to a `reflection-config.json`

EDIT:
After running the result of `quarkusBuild` with `-agentlib:native-image-agent=config-merge-dir=...`, I added the resulting `reflect-config.json` to `src/main/resourcecs/`.

Building native with `-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=reflect-config.json` completes successfully, but gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:70)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:44)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Annotation is not a registered qualifier: interface jakarta.enterprise.inject.Any
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.Qualifiers.verifyQualifier(Qualifiers.java:152)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.Qualifiers.verify(Qualifiers.java:47)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.resolveObservers(ArcContainerImpl.java:846)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.EventImpl.createNotifier(EventImpl.java:177)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.notifierOrNull(ArcContainerImpl.java:511)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.<init>(ArcContainerImpl.java:195)
    at io.quarkus.arc.Arc.initialize(Arc.java:39)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.initContainer(ArcRecorder.java:47)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ArcProcessor$generateResources844392269.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ArcProcessor$generateResources844392269.deploy(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: when you try without reflection config json and without     "additional-build-args: --initialize-at-run-time=io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl,--initialize-at-run-time=io.quarkus.runtime.generated.Config" what error do you get ? quarkus is good with configuring all native classes, so it should work out of the box I think.